# How to convert a a type number in format 2300 to hours and compare to current time with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given a number `1500` which is supposed to represent the time 15:00 (3pm). I'd like to convert it to a moment time and be able to compare it to the current time.
How to make this conversion and how to get the current time in that same format to be able to compare it?

Answer (score 1):

```
const now = moment();
const time = moment('1500', 'hhmm');

const diff = moment.duration(now.diff(time));
```

Then to compare you can use
`diff.minutes()`, `diff.seconds()`, or `diff.hours()`

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date: `moment();`

Then you can set the hours and minutes: `moment().set("hour", numberString.substring(0, 2)).set("minute", numberString.substring(2, 4));`

Altogether that'd be:

```js
const numberString = "1500";
const now = moment();
const nowAtNumberStringTime = moment().set("hour", numberString.substring(0, 2)).set("minute", numberString.substring(2, 4));
const difference = now.diff(nowAtNumberStringTime);
console.log(difference);
```